# Best way to query data to achieve minimum latency in AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I need advice for the following use case.

I have around 50 GB json data in s3 bucket with around 200 attributes.

Now I want to access this data using a REST api with some filters.

I tried storing the data in DynamoDB but it has limitation that we can only filter data based on keys and to filter on new key we need to first create **Global Secondary Index** for the same. Also this serves the request slowly.

I would like suggestions on how can I improve the search over this data.

Available options are:

1. MongoDB/DocumentDB in AWS
2. ElasticSearch
3. RDS
4. Athena
5. Redshift

If there is any other better option, please suggest.

I am trying to achieve latency in ms if possible.

Also what can be the best fit for such use case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the amount of data going to grow? Or will it always be 50 GB?

Comment: [mapreduce](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-amazon-elastic-mapreduce/) , [emr](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) . going outside of the managed space [ecs](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)

Comment: Data is bound to grow but max target for now is 200 GB.. Also I am open to EMR, ECS but how to achieve the speed. I am already processing it  through glue.

Comment: If you want arbitrary search/filter queries and very low latency then it's likely that the best fit is Elasticsearch imo. The tradeoff is cost and management overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have extensive experience with elasticsearch performance but have worked with most of other popular systems mentioned and IMO best is to use Elasticsearch in this case as in case of Mongo and DynamoDB filters are costly and RDBMS is not fast for complex filtered queries and creating indices in RDBMS is costly and adding new index on existing columns requires significant overhead.

While Elasticsearch tokenize the data and add them to inverted index for faster search and retrieval and 200 GB is nothing for Elastic scale and its easy to setup and scale and works for simple use-cases like yours.

Most important thing is that filters are by default cached at elasticsearch side so you don't have to implement additional caching like Redis, refer [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) for more details.

Comment: So we are implementing DynamoDB streams to load indexes in elasticsearch. Then using elasticsearch for quering the index. Thanks for your answer